# Screwturn Wiki Form Auth Provider

Tags: authentication, configuration, provider, screwturn

I'm attempting to use the ScrewTurnFormsAuth provider, found [here](http://screwwikiformauth.codeplex.com/). I can upload it and enable it, but I can't set it up as the default provider because it's not appearing in the user provider drop-down. It shows as loaded and enabled, but I can't set it to the default provider because it's missing in the drop down.

I was able to do this with a different user provider without any problems, except that the provider is unusable on my current host. So I'd like to test this provider to see if I can use it there instead.

So, anyone know what I can do to make this provider work? Do I need to tweak something? Is there somewhere I can look to figure out why it won't appear in the drop-down? Any and all clues appreciated.